# Should an EU-based company add VAT for services provided to non-EU-based charity?

Tags: taxes

I have just set up a UK-based company, and need some guidance on taxation. The company is not VAT-regsitered, which may mean I cannot charge VAT in any case. The The service being provided is some teaching via webinar - I will be in the UK but the students will be outside of the EU. In addition, the body organising the webinar is a non-profit organisation. Can anybody please help explain what I should charge (if anything) in addition to the standard fee? Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only tax you can add is VAT, but since you are not VAT registered then you cannot charge it. If you do you will be fined significantly for tax fraud. So you should just set a price and charge only that.

Comment: Many thanks - that's extremely helpful to know